# Strange error with AIR AS3 Projector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I'm using FlashDevelop, attempting to put together an AIR AS3 Projector project. Basically I'm just creating a new project, with no code.  When I hit F5 a cmd window pops up, and says,

```
Starting AIR Debug Launcher...

invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0
Press any key to continue. . .
```

I asked about this over in the FlashDevelop forum and the moderator told me to download a merged Flex SDK + AIR SDK 4.0 using Tools->Install Software.  I did that, it did not help (although possibly it may help with other things).

What's going on here?

Comment: Don't know about FlahDevelop, but in FlashBuilder you get this error, when the air sdk version number in application-descriptor.xml from your project does'nt match the installed sdk. After downloading the new sdk you might need to tell your IDE, it should compile against it, too. [This tutorial](http://francescomaisto.wordpress.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-change-air-sdk-in-flashdevelop/) might help you.

Comment: @T.Richter, you may want to post that as an answer. I think you're right.

Comment: Yes, T. Richter, that turned out to be the answer- thanks!  Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turned it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs, if the sdk version in the application-descriptor.xml from your project does'nt match the installed sdk. 
After downloading the new sdk you must tell your IDE, it should compile against it, too. 
This [tutorial](http://francescomaisto.wordpress.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-change-air-sdk-in-flashdevelop/) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manually dowload them here:

AIR SDK

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

FLEX SDK

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

then extract the SDK to a folder on your computer and specify the correct path as described in Step 2 of this tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Use Netbeans, 
Create a PHP Project, and in the 'Run configuration' , choose 'Script(run in command line) for the 'Run As' parameter.
choose the adl.exe file from your sdk install folder (mine is F:\softwares\AirSDKCompiler\bin\adl.exe )  for the 'PHP Interpreter' parameter!

set the 'Index File' parameter to your Application Descriptor file (First_app.xml or whatever your file name is..)

in your application descriptor, check for this code (check the version of your sdk)

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0" minimumPatchLevel="0">
```

Deleter your default index.php, and just Run > the project, 
It works like a champion!!!!

Comment: This is not a PHP project.

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question.